# About the equation $u\cdot u-v\cdot v=\det(u,v)$

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, determinant

EDIT II: A little background information.

My spare-time interest at the moment is in vector fields and differential equations; in particular I'm trying to understand how the superposition principle fails in two dimensional ($1$-dof) systems of nonlinear equations.

One problem is determining the equilibria of the system.

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x} = F_1(x,y) + G_1(x,y)\\
\dot{y} = F_2(x,y) + G_2(x,y)
\end{eqnarray}
be a system of (nonlinear) differential equations, where $x,y,\in\mathbb{R}$. All functions are smooth.

The problem I'm focusing on is finding a link between the equilibria of the sub-systems
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x} = F_1(x,y) \qquad \dot{x} = G_1(x,y)\\
\dot{y} = F_2(x,y) \qquad \dot{y} = G_2(x,y)
\end{eqnarray}
and the equilibria of the "sum-system".

Considering the $\mathbb{R}^2$ vectors (better, the two functions $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$)
\begin{eqnarray}
u(x,y)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
F_1\\
F_2
\end{array}
\right)\qquad
v(x,y)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
G_1\\
G_2
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

The problem of finding the zeroes of $u+v$, which correspond to the equilibria of the sum-system, can be seen as finding all the couples of vectors that satisfy the following conditions:

$1$) the two vectors have the same norm, i.e. $\|u\| = \|v\|$

$2$) the two vectors point in opposite directions, i.e. $u = kv$ with $k<0$.

Now, the second condition implies that the two vectors have to be linearly dependent, so it could be interesting to consider the (relaxed) condition

$2b$) the two vectors are dependent, i.e. $\det(u,v)=0$.

Futher relaxing the constraints (hoping to find useful stuff along the way) I looked at the conditions

\begin{equation}
\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2 = \varepsilon\qquad\text{and}\qquad \det(u,v)=\varepsilon
\end{equation}
which finally led me to a single over-relaxed condition which is
\begin{equation}
\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2 = \det(u,v)
\end{equation}
i.e. the equation of the title. The locus of the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since $u$ and $v$ are functions of the phase-space variables) contains the zeros of the sum-system, and actually I find the equation handsome enough to be of an aesthetic interest (to me, at least!).

My question is simple: is there anything in literature regarding this equation?

EDIT I: $u,v$ are vectors in a vector space $V$ of dimension $2$;

$\det(u,v)$ is the determinant seen as a bilinear alternating form on $V\times V$

Comment: what does $\mathrm{det} (u, v)$ stand here for?

Comment: is this only in 2 dimensions?

Comment: Any two linearly independent vectors span a two-dimensional space. Please give an example of the equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @AritroPathak yes, I edited the question for clarity

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Excuse me I don't understand your question- why does it seem that I am defining the determinant? It is the usual determinant of a 2x2 matrix (or a couple of vectors)

Comment: Excuse me, but it's the same as considering the equation $\sqrt{x+y}=x+y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm not defining $\sqrt{\cdot}$, I'm looking at the solution of the equation, i.e. at the subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2:U=\{(x,y)|\sqrt{x+y}=x+y\}$

Comment: Ah, damn. I did not realise that! All good.

Comment: Let me clarify this: my understanding is that you do not need it solved, but you want a reference covering generalisations or techniques of solution of said equation. Am I correct?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli correct

Comment: Why close this question? Is it too broad?

Comment: I think there's room to clarify your question, hence unclear what you're asking. For one the normal way to use the term determinant is to take the determinant of a matrix - I assume that you by $\det(u,v)$ means the determinant of the matrix with $u$ and $v$ as column vectors. Also in the comments it's suggested that you would like to know about the solutions to the equation, but that's only mentioned in comments. It's also mentioned in comments about generalizations to the equation, but then if I understood it correctly you would need more vectors.

Comment: Nevertheless I retracted the vote to close. The solutions to this equation seem to be hypersurfaces in $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Also in order to be able to find litterature on it the equation must be interresting in some way. Why is this equation interresting to you? Maybe that would be a clue on where to search.

Comment: @skyking I edited the question and added some context. Thanks for pointing that out.